# RequireJS dependencies breaking by different http header

Tags: http, symfony, nginx, http-headers, requirejs

I had a hard time figuring out where the problem is. Actually I am using Symfony2 for serving AngularJS by RequireJS. Everything works fine within the dev environment, but in production it breaks.

So the problem sticks inside the different http header (one is served by sf2 / php the other one by nginx).

The working header looks like http://pastebin.com/xJQZ3eRn
The not working header looks like http://pastebin.com/xYD2QYHd

Any ideas? I already added the same Cache-Control which was missing for the static javascript file which was served by nginx. Maybe someone else knows more?

Answer (score 0):

You could try serving your assets as protocol agnostic, I've had issues with this before when going from HTTP to HTTPS with hard coded URLs.

use

```
//some.domain.com/js/appmain.js
```

instead of

```
http://some.domain.com/js/appmain.js
```

That way the server will choose how to serve it.

Not sure if this is related since your working file seems to be HTTP as well.